# Add dynamic URL (or button) to each node in Drupal

Tags: drupal, cck

I've used CCK to create a 'Travel Offer' content-type which basically just lists the details for a travel package.

My question is how to have a button or link on each node (when the user views it) that will link to a url that includes the title of the current node (eg: example.com/requestQuote/Title_Of_This_Node).

I haven't implemented my system yet so I am free to change the content-type to include a button field or something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be by adding a `node-your_content_type_name.tpl.php` file into your theme folder. (If you haven't done this before, all you need to do is create a duplicate of node.tpl.php and rename the copy to `node-your_content_type_name.tpl.php`)

The '$title' variable is available within the node template, so it should be easy to craft a little bit of PHP to print out the appropriate link target.

Edit:

Now, if you want to get a little bit fancier, you could build the link to reference the unaliased node page ('example.com/requestQuote/node/11569' or whatever) and feed it through Drupal's handy `l()` function to build the hyperlink.

The advantage here is that you won't need to worry about the link changing if the title changes, even though `l()` will automatically update the actual hyperlink that's displayed to the user.

This will probably make the custom coding on your 'example.com/requestQuote' page a lot easier too, since you can work directly with the node ids and don't need to parse titles.